# Load/Append images into galleria dynamically "in steps"

Tags: jquery, ajax, galleria

I am using ajax to fetch the image data (json object) and to load them into Galleria. Since there are like ~250 images I would like to split them up in say groups of 30.

Now here's the interesting part. After the first 30 images are loaded I would want the next group of 30 images to start loading, and when these are done loading the next group should load and so on (all appended to the same gallery).

Here's what I am currently doing: when the user reaches the last image in the current group, I am using "loadfinish" event of Galleria to append the next 30 images to the gallery. But there is a flaw here. The user won't know there are more than 30 images until he/she actually clicks on the last image.

***Ideally*** what I would want is to find out when galleria has finished loading all the images that were supplied to it. The "loadfinish" method just tells me when the current image has finished loading.

I have also tried jquery .load(), but it won't tell me when the galleria DOM ('.galleria-image") has finished loading :(.

I am open to any solution that gets me around this problem. Thanks!